# tkinter error when trying to import matplotlib.pyplot in Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, python, pip

I'm using Arch Linux with Gnome. I used [pip](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/any/python-pip/) to install matplotlib in my home directory:

```bsh
pip install --user matplotlib
```

This seemed to work, and when I use Python I can successfully `import matplotlib`. However, if I try to import `matplotlib.pyplot` I get the error

```py
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2374, in <module>
    switch_backend(rcParams["backend"])
  File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 207, in switch_backend
    backend_mod = importlib.import_module(backend_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import _backend_tk
  File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/_backend_tk.py", line 5, in <module>
    import tkinter as Tk
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ImportError: libtk8.6.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Why am I getting an error and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem occurred because I didn't have *Tk* or *tkinter* installed. Installing the [tk](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/tk/) package solved the problem:

```
pacman -S tk
```